# RegEx that matches a string of numbers in a particular format?

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will tell if a string is in the following format. The groups of numbers must be comma delimited. Can contain a range of numbers separated by a -

```
 300, 200-400, 1, 250-300
```

The groups can be in any order.

This is what I have so far, but it's not matching the entire string. It's only matching the groups of numbers.

```
([0-9]{1,3}-?){1,2},?
```

Comment: Can there be negative number?

Comment: Only positive and the most it will contain is 3 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(\d+(-\d+)?)(,\s*(\d+(-\d+)?))*$
```

Comment: Problem is, it doesn't check the whole string. It should start and end with anchors and should additionally check for max of 3 numbers. As it stands now LAWL230498234092840238942-3OMG! will validate.

Comment: @FailedDev: It depends on the language. If Java, no problem. If other language, the anchor may be needed. From the comment, it seems like number of digits is more like input constraint rather than validation constraint.

Comment: Well then, fixed. I added the anchors.

Comment: @nhahtdh:  It isn't *Java* that automatically anchors the match at both ends, it's Java's `matches()` method.  There's also a `find()` method (available only through the Matcher object) that performs the traditional, free-floating kind of match.  But it's a good idea to add the anchors even if you're using `matches()`; it communicates your intent more clearly, and it's easier to port the regex to a different flavor (should you need to).

Comment: @AlanMoore: I'm assuming `matches()` method, since this is a validation question. But I get your point about including anchor.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
^(?:\d{1,3}(?:-\d{1,3})?)(?:,\s*\d{1,3}(?:-\d{1,3})?|$)+
```

Since you didn't specify the number ranges I leave this to you. In any case you should do math with regex :)

Explanation:

```
"
^                       # Assert position at the beginning of the string
(?:                     # Match the regular expression below
   \\d                  # Match a single digit 0..9
      {1,3}             # Between one and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   (?:                  # Match the regular expression below
      -                 # Match the character “-” literally
      \\d               # Match a single digit 0..9
         {1,3}          # Between one and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   )?                   # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
(?:                     # Match the regular expression below
                        # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      ,                 # Match the character “,” literally
      \\s               # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
         *              # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      \\d               # Match a single digit 0..9
         {1,3}          # Between one and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      (?:               # Match the regular expression below
         -              # Match the character “-” literally
         \\d            # Match a single digit 0..9
            {1,3}       # Between one and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      )?                # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   |                    # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      \$                # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
)+                      # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"
```

**[image: Test samples]**

Comment: Instead of `|$)+`, why not `)*$`?

Comment: Well I have multiple lines being tested so I just put that in the bracket. Will work either way :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
/^([0-9]{1,3}(-[0-9]{1,3})?)(,\s?([0-9]{1,3}(-[0-9]{1,3})?))*$/
```

Comment: This is probably good for extracting, but the OP wants to check the format. Add a bit more and it should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You need some repetition:

```
(?:([0-9]{1,3}-?){1,2},?)+
```

To ensure that the numbers are correct, i.e. that you don't match numbers like 010, you might want to change the regex slightly. I also changed the range part of the regex, so that you don't match things like 100-200- but only 100 or 100-200, and added support for whitespaces after the comma (optional):

```
(?:(([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2})(-[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2})?){1,2},?\s*)+
```

Also, depending on what you want to capture, you might want to change the capturing brackets `()` to non capturing ones `(?:)`

**UPDATE**

A revised version based on the latest comments:

```
^\s*(?:(([1-9][0-9]{0,2})(-[1-9][0-9]{0,2})?)(?:,\s*|$))+$
```

Comment: I think this might return true for cases outside valid set. e.g. `345-345-`

Comment: As it is now, your regex will match whitespace *anywhere*, not just after a comma.  That's because the comma itself is optional.  Also, please don't use `{1}` in regexes.  It's pure clutter; it has absolutely no effect on the match.

Comment: @AlanMoore - see edit - the `{1}` was just a copy paste error though

Comment: @Joanna: Fails to invalidate `343-546-231`

Comment: @nhahtdh - updated - removed this `{1,2}` which shouldn't have been there in the first place

Comment: @Joanna: `345, ` will be accepted by your regex. Anyway, IMO, not really a big deal. I'm not sure if there is any other way to represent regex for `S --> TOKEN DELIMITER S | TOKEN` type of grammar, but I usually see `TOKEN (DELIMITER TOKEN)*` type of regex.

Answer (score -1):

```
([0-9-]+),\s([0-9-]+),\s([0-9-]+),\s([0-9-]+)
```

Comment: Too weak. Some cases which should not match will match.

Answer (score -1):

Try this regular expression

```
^(([0-9]{1,3}-?){1,2},?\s*)+$
```

Comment: This is another loose expression. It will fail this test: `324 342`

Comment: Quote from original question: "groups of numbers must be comma delimited"

Comment: I interpret the statement as a validation condition, rather than constraint on the input. Your regex fails to invalidate the case.